# retrieve flashvar from Flex3 using mxml

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flashvars

Is it possible to retrieve flashvar parameter in mxml code and if so how? Up to now i have been using `Application.application.parameter.name` to get what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to it:

```
<mx:Label text="{Application.application.parameters.name}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that's the only way to get it - you'll have to use that bit of actionscript.  How would you like to use it in MXML?  If you post an example of what you'd expect it to look like we might have more ideas.